# Adding email & call links to homescreen breaks in iOS 7

Tags: ios, iphone

I have a mobile-optimized website with the necessary code to it available as a webapp. This site includes links to place calls and send emails. This has worked for years on iOS. However, it no longer works on iOS 7. Here's a stripped down version of the code. I verified that after "adding to homescreen", opening the webapp, and tapping the phone number, it works in iOS 6 but not iOS 7.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;" />
<meta name="apple-touch-fullscreen" content="yes" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
</head>
<body>
<a href="tel:(212) 555-5555">&nbsp;(212) 555-5555</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Is this a bug in iOS 7? Or do I need to add something new for it to work in iOS 7?

Answer (score 0):

When I look at the RFC's ([# 2806, which defines the "`tel:`" URL scheme](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2806.txt)), I never see parenthesis characters in the example URL's.

And [in the "Phone Links" example in Apple's URL Scheme Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/PhoneLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007893-SW1), Apple shows how they use HTML that looks like: "`<a href="tel:1-408-555-5555">1-408-555-5555</a>`".

My guess is that - as of iOS 7 - Apple has tightened up a bit on how "`tel:`" URL's can be defined (e.g. parenths might require escaping or proper encoding).

So try getting rid of the parenths and see if you have better luck.

Comment: Michael, thank you for your reply. However, I tried this, and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score -1):

IOS7 can not link from webapps, you can't open URL's, App Store, Youtube either.

So it's not a "tel:" issue :-)

But they do work if you remove:

And make it just a home screen bookmark, not a webapp.

Mac

Comment: I'm not sure if you've missed a part of the answer, it seems your post is incomplete. What are they supposed to remove?